# Saving to a database using a dao and a for loop, save being overwritten

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, intellij-idea

My program takes two strings, splits them into an arraylist, finds common strings, and allows user to store the common strings with a checkbox form.

```
public String savedResults(@ModelAttribute @Valid Trigger newTrigger, User aUser, Model model, @RequestParam String aTrigger){

    model.addAttribute("aTrigger", aTrigger);

    aUser.getUid();

    newTrigger.setUser(aUser);
    String[] manyTriggers = aTrigger.split(",");

    for(String item : manyTriggers) {
        newTrigger.setKnownTriggers(item);
        triggerDao.save(newTrigger);
    }
    return "html file"
}
```

The problem is getting each selected item to save in a new row. The `for` loop is overwriting the `dao.save` each time it iterates through `manyTriggers`, instead of saving it to the database and continuing on to save the next item in a new row in the database.

Comment: Try creating and saving a new instance of `Trigger` each time in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a new instance of `Trigger`each time you save it inside your `for` loop, as following:

```
public String savedResults(@ModelAttribute @Valid Trigger newTrigger, User aUser, Model model, @RequestParam String aTrigger){

    model.addAttribute("aTrigger", aTrigger);

    aUser.getUid();

    String[] manyTriggers = aTrigger.split(",");

    for(String item : manyTriggers) {
        Trigger newTrigger = new Trigger();
        newTrigger.setUser(aUser);
        newTrigger.setKnownTriggers(item);
        triggerDao.save(newTrigger);
    }
    return "html file"
}
```

---

Another option is to use the JPA `persist()` method, that always create a new object (note that using this mwthod you wont be able to update existing records). See:

```
    public String savedResults(@ModelAttribute @Valid Trigger newTrigger, User aUser, Model model, @RequestParam String aTrigger){

    model.addAttribute("aTrigger", aTrigger);

    aUser.getUid();

    newTrigger.setUser(aUser);
    String[] manyTriggers = aTrigger.split(",");

    for(String item : manyTriggers) {
        newTrigger.setKnownTriggers(item);
        triggerDao.persist(newTrigger);
    }
    return "html file"
}
```